# Which application run on multiple tcp connection?

Tags: tcp, mapreduce, cluster-computing

Which application run on multiple tcp connections that are effect interactively.
For example, there are three connections will be created. When first one is slower than others, and the others will limit by the slower one.
I want to know which application have this situation.